# generating a 4 digit number in sequence (java)

Tags: java

trying to create a unique code and apart of the code format is generating a 4 digit sequence number. (increment of 1) so it would produce XX0001, XX0002.

was messing around more to do the sequence one but erm i cant seem to do it but this is what i have that doesn't work ;c

i did this but it generated xx0001 for all my items:

```
int number = 0;
String s = String.format("%04d", ++number);
stringBuilder.append(s);
return stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: If `number` is initially 0, and then you do `++number`, it will always be 1, so you will always get "0001".

Comment: You need to store the number for use in the next call. Also, please don't post new questions that are basically dealing with the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Make `number` field `static`.

Since you are calling function it recreates it several times every time with number equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

While incrementing the value, you should do it in a loop.

```
for (int number = 0; number < 9999; number++) {
   // not writing the code here intentionally, try to figure it out and you will do it.
   // hint: append in the string builder 
}
```

you can replace `9999` with your desired last value of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are always initializing number as 0, It will always be 1.
So the number should always be incremented by one, therefore you need to keep track of it when you access it in the function. So static variable is used. Check below the example.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(BuildCode());
    System.out.println(BuildCode());
    System.out.println(BuildCode());
    
  }
  static int number = 1; // Static variable, to keep track of latest number
  public static String BuildCode() {
    String code = String.format("%04d", ++number);
    return code;
  }
}
```

Note: you can create the function BuildCode and pass an int num argument which indicated the latest number used - This number can be obtained from the database, File, or a static variable - .